# I have two subnets created with openwrt. how can i set up NAT hairpinning from first to second network?

Tags: networking, dns, nat, openwrt

I have created on OpenWRT 3 different network interfaces. WAN for internet, LAN for my personal network, and MANAGEMENT for my hosted servers. These two networks are seperate. seperate DCHP, DNS, etc. just two completely seperate networks...

so what i would like to do, is set up OpenWRT so that when i go to myservers.com on my LAN network, it would loopback on my external IP and basically serve me what my MANAGEMENT network is hosting.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "hairpinning" here – it is only needed if the request is to be NATed back to the *same* subnet as it came from. That is the case for most users, as they only have one subnet in the first place, but is *not* the case here – you're going from LAN to MGMT, so the network topology already ensures that the router will be in the middle, so hairpinning is irrelevant; all you need is to adjust the interface limitation that you have on the DNAT (port-forwarding) rules currently.

Note though, that if you forward port 80 you will lose access to the OpenWRT web UI that's also on port 80 – NAT is based on IP addresses and TCP ports; it does not know what *domain* you are trying to access, so if you DNAT the router's port 80 to your hosted server, you DNAT port 80 _regardless of domain. For example, if you go to `http://192.168.1.1`, that will also be DNATed to the server the same way as `http://myserver.com` is.

It might be a better idea to configure OpenWRT's dnsmasq to override the IP address that `myserver.com` resolves to (i.e. use "split DNS"), so that inside your LAN it directly resolves to the hosted server's IP, not to the router's IP as usual.

So with that in mind – the only change to make port forwardings work from LAN *should be* to select the correct "External zone" in the port-forward rule; i.e. add a second forward rule with "External zone: LAN" alongside the current one you have for WAN.